# Making circle appears behind object that's moving from Point A to Point B in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shapes

I've got this code in AS3 that's making a boat moves from pointA to point B..etc

```
tween = new Tween(boat, "x", None.easeNone, boat.x, lastClick.x, 1, true); 
tweenY = new Tween(boat, "y", None.easeNone, boat.y, lastClick.y, 1, true);
```

[(video here)](https://streamable.com/nprtg)

I'd like to add some circle appearing behind the boat (like a path on a map).

I've tried with lines but it doesn't suits very well (as it appears instantly and, of course, it's not circle).

```
my_shape.graphics.moveTo(lastClick.x, lastClick.y); 
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(event.currentTarget.x, event.currentTarget.y); 
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(event.currentTarget.x, event.currentTarget.y);
```

Do you know how could I add some circle going from `lastClick` to `event.currentTarget` ? [(video of an example here)](https://streamable.com/krh8k)

Comment: Prior to asking question please read the official documentation or google it because "as3 draw circle" outputs a perfectly relevant link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawCircle() Then, you need to subscribe for Event.ENTER_FRAME event and draw circles where boat is at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using tweens you could draw your points when your tween updates. If you are writing your code directly on the timeline you might need to remove "private" from the functions:

```
// draw a point every X pixels
private var DISTANCE_BETWEEN_POINTS:int = 20;
private var pointsArray:Array = [];
private var lastPoint:Point;

tween = new Tween(boat, "x", null, boat.x, lastClick.x, 1, true);
tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onTweenUpdate);
tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd);

tweenY = new Tween(boat, "y", null, boat.y, lastClick.y, 1, true);
tweenY.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onTweenUpdate);
tweenY.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd);

// for the start we assume the last drawn point was at the boat origin
lastPoint = new Point(boat.x, boat.y);    

// called on every tween update
private function onTweenUpdate(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    // draw a point if the distance to the last point is greater than DISTANCE_BETWEEN_POINTS
    if (distance(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.x, boat.y, lastPoint.y) > DISTANCE_BETWEEN_POINTS)
    {
        // pseudocode here. Add your points as movieclips or just draw circles
        // you might adjust the point position as this will draw a point over the boat.
        // you might want to add a layer where you draw points that will be under your boat
        var point:MovieClip = new PointMC();
        point.x = boat.x;
        point.y = boat.y;
        addChild(point);

        // remember the last drawn point position for the next one
        lastPoint = new Point(boat.x, boat.y);

        // add point to array so we can remove them when the tween is done
        pointsArray.push(point);
    }
}

// called when a tween ends
// remove event listeners so your tweens can be garbage collected
private function onTweenEnd(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    tween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onTweenUpdate);
    tween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd);
    tweenY.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onTweenUpdate);
    tweenY.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd);

    removePoints();
}

private function removePoints():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++)
    {
        removeChild(pointsArray[i]);
    }

    pointsArray = [];
}

// measures the distance between two points
private function distance(x1:Number, x2:Number, y1:Number, y2:Number):Number
{
    var dx:Number = x1 - x2;
    var dy:Number = y1 - y2;
    return Math.abs(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
}
```

I would strongly advise you to switch to the [TweenLite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as) for the tween movements - it is very easy to plug in and you can do all of this in one line and dont have to mess up with event listeners and stuff like that:

```
// move the boat to x and y in one go - DONE :)
TweenLite.to(boat, 1, {x: lastClick.x, y: lastClick.y, onUpdate: onTweenUpdate});
```

Plus it can do tons of other stuff like bezier curves, reverse etc. Once you get used to it you will ask yourself how you lived without it before :)

Comment: Thx for the answer ! I've got this error though.. Error 1119 can't access the property TWEEN_UPDATE via Static Class. Any idea why ?

Comment: It's indeed working ! Thx. Don't know what is the purpose of `TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH` but if I desactivate the line `tweenY.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd);` and `tweenY.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd);` it's working..

Comment: The purpose is that you remove the event listeners again after the motion was done so the garbage collector can free up the memory. And it should remove the dots. I've just noticed that I forgot to change "addEventListener" to "removeEventListener" in the onTweenEnd function

Comment: Missed your other comment, it should say TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH not TWEEN_UPDATE of course, edited my reply